# Executing Python Command from Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So what I want to do is that I want to create an evaluation command in discord.py. So when the user says

```
.evaluate print("hi")
```

I want it to to send the code to python and run it. I seen ways with `subprocess.Popen` or `os.system` or `system` generally, but it only runs `shell` commands. I was wondering how I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

````
import contextlib
import io
@bot.command()
async def eval(ctx, *, code):
    str_obj = io.StringIO() #Retrieves a stream of data
    try:
        with contextlib.redirect_stdout(str_obj):
            exec(code)
    except Exception as e:
        return await ctx.send(f"```{e.__class__.__name__}: {e}```")
    await ctx.send(f'```{str_obj.getvalue()}```')
````

Keep in mind, the example above is very simple, and can be expanded on. For example, `exec` has a `globals` argument so that you can use global(pre-defined) variables in your eval statements. You can even format your code so that you can include: ```py

{your code here}```

around your eval command. Whatever you do, **make sure no one has access to your eval command but you**. Seriously, they might as well be sitting at your computer if they have access to it.

Comment: How would I allow block codes like with
 ```py
#code
```

Comment: If someone has access to your eval command, they will be able to do horrible things with it. They can delete channels, ban members, and get personal information from your computer (or the vps your bot is run on). The bottom line is to not give it to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the python [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function. Of course allowing people to execute commands in your script is a security risk, please proceed with extreme caution. Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, this type of activity should be avoided.

Try:

```py
@client.command()
async def evaluate(ctx, *, cmd=None):
    try:
        eval(cmd)
        await ctx.send(f'Your bot friend executed your command --> {cmd}')
    except:
        print(f'{cmd} is an invalid command')
        await ctx.send(f'Your bot friend could not execute an invalid command --> {cmd}')
```

Console Output

```
None is an invalid command
hi
nocommand(junk) is an invalid command
```

Discord dialog (using a "?" prefix instead of ".":

[image]

Comment: why is this dangerous? Like how is it a security risk?

Comment: @AK-10CA-GlenforestSS2172
If any user can run python commands, then they can do anything on the system that the bot is running, such as installing additional programs from the internet, running malware, stealing environment variables, and harvesting any personal information on the bot's hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the command being owner only.

```
@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def evaluate(ctx, *, cmd=None):
    try:
        eval(cmd)
        await ctx.send(f'Your bot friend executed your command --> {cmd}')
    except:
        print(f'{cmd} is an invalid command')
        await ctx.send(f'Your bot friend could not execute an invalid command --> {cmd}')
```